# Unable to automate keytab generation

Tags: scala, kerberos

I am trying to automate keytab generation from an API in Scala and am  encountering errors.

My API is being called by my test case in Ubuntu, my API is connecting to my Windows machine to run a PowerShell script which runs the following `ktpass` command:

```
ktpass -out $keytabFilePath -mapUser $mapU -princ $principal -pass $passwd -crypto All -pType KRB5_NT_SRV_INST /target  $target +Answer
```

Using legacy password setting method:

```
WARNING: search term '(& (objectClass=person) (samaccountname=computername$))' produced
no results.
ktpass : Failed to locate user '(& (objectClass=person) (samaccountname=computername$))'.
At C:\ProgramData\HXBootStrap.psm1:6702 char:9
+         ktpass -out $keytabFilePath -mapUser $mapU -princ $principal  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Failed to locat...tname=computername$))'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Could not locate user.

Comment: Is `hvca$` a computer object or a gMSA in AD? Typically that's what the trailing `$` means. If it's a regular user it shouldn't end in that.

Comment: this question tagged with java - does it really has anything to do with java?

Comment: The error is saying there is no computer account `hvca` (at least on the DC where the query executed).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.

I have solved it by creating a task on windows task scheduler and running the task from my scala API.

Apparently the problem was because ktpass does not work as expected when invoked remotely. It has to be run from a local invocation.